# What Lightroom settings should I use to export photo collages for printing?

Tags: lightroom, printing, collage

I have several collages composed in Lightroom, and would like to print them at 21x15. Can you please recommend appropriate Lightroom settings for exporting them? I would like to avoid any crop or black/white strips on printed photos, once I give photos to the print company.

Comment: I noticed a lot of down voting, it may be that the question is not understood (I know I did not understand it).  Are you asking how to make collages with lightroom?  Or are you making the collage as a single image elsewhere, and then asking how to export it?   Lightroom is not a tool really for doing collages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question is about exporting already existing collage composed in Lightroom. 
All I wanted to know, is what export settings I should use to have my photos printed in 21x15 photo without crop or white straps....
I know that this might be sill question for somebody who using it everyday, but I just want to be sure before I will start doing my 100 collages and in the end I've end up with cropped images due to bad resolution or so....
As for question it self, I've already started to do them so it's a bit outdated...I've used export landscape A4 format and 3:4 ratio

Comment: @JZK my apologies, I edited the question originally, and I fear I might have added to the confusion or misunderstanding. I've edited it further to clarify based on your last comment. But please, by all means, if my edits are incorrect or misleading, please correct them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the clarification in the comments and I think the edited question I think the real answer is you should not use the Lightroom Print option for sending images to a print company, but should use Export.

Generally speaking you should crop the image to the right aspect ratio first, then export without resizing in the format (JPG, TIFF) and color space (sRGB, Adobe RGB, etc.) that the print company wants.  If they do not specify use JPG and sRGB.

It is usually best not to resize, but let the print company do so, unless they specifically require that you resize.

There is also a sharpen option for the export, where you can select the amount of sharpening and type of planned media. Generally, if you have modestly sharpened, you can do a medium or low amount of sharpening here for the correct media; if you have strongly sharpened your image in lightroom you may want to turn this off.

Using the Print option with JPG as output is possible, but it goes through extra steps and involves borders and such you normally do not want when sending to a custom lab to produce prints, and you risk getting something like borders twice  - once from the module and once from the lab.